# Is global variables are allowed in an application created by Cordova and Ionic?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have build a Cordova application using Ionic 1.3 in an android device, but it didn't works exactly as it works in the browser, especially when it comes to data.

I guess that my issues due to some js global functions and variables, which I have declared in the top of the code.

Is that true ?

Comment: No. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It is hard to test without knowing the code for the problem. One or two javascript functions may not work for instance webGL wasn't really supported in android webview. Cordova and ionic packages your app into an android webview container. You also cannot use fullscreen javascript yet. What you can and cannot use is listed https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Comment: I can't post the code because it's not my property !

Comment: I will read about web views and try to fix the problem, Thank you very much David, your comment is very helpful

Comment: Some of things webview cannot do like check device orientation can be set in config.xml before you build.